# Excel - Change from Decimal to Hexadecimal

Tags: excel, vba, macros, hex, decimal

I'm creating a simple program where to convert decimal to hexadecimal. However while converting using =DEC2HEX(B5), i get the answer of B26801FB. However the correct answer is 0B26801FB where the zero in front the string is missing. The B5 value is 2993160699 in the General format.

I have tested using all the format but i dint get 0B26801FB. Please Help

[image]

Comment: If you want the answer to show leading zeros, you could use the `Places` option, eg `=DEC2HEX(B5, 9)`.

Comment: hi Ambie, yea, i have tried that solutions too but no luck

Comment: Why do you say B26801FB is a wrong value?

Comment: @VincentG , Initially 0B26801FB is converted to decimal by using =HEX2DEC formula. By using that i get 2993160699. However when i want reconvert back to hexadecimal, i get B26801FB where the zero is missing.

Comment: Leading zero are usually meaningless. If you want to force them, you need to use the answer provided by Ambie or David, with the correct number of places (in your case, 9). If you want to keep the original formatting, you will need to memorize it somewhere. If you want to have only one leading zero, whatever the length of the string is, there is ways to do that too (for example `=IF(B5=0;"0";DEC2HEX(B5;LEN(DEC2HEX(B5))+1))`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the return of the value with a number of positions.

```
=DEC2HEX(B5;NUMBER_POSITIONS)

=DEC2HEX(B5;9)
```

Take a look the picture...

[image]

Comment: Hi david, i plan to not add a code for this. plan to do by using formula. However i will be really appreciate there is code for this. For more information, i have uploaded the pic on my question above.

Comment: @Jeeva i have edit my answer. Take a look if it runs.

Comment: But there is 2 zeros infront. The answer should be 0B26801FB. By the way what is the cell format?

Comment: I have writed it @Jeeva, see my answer please. You can change the number after the cell. Change 10 by 9 only.

Comment: Initially 0B26801FB is converted to decimal by using =HEX2DEC formula. By using that i get 2993160699. However when i want reconvert back to hexadecimal, i get B26801FB where the zero is missing.

Comment: It runs ok in my excel. Pease dont forget to accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: its working now. Seems that both type data is must be general. Thanks